# Closing previous window from JFileChooser Open button

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jfilechooser

I am making a file opening wizard, and the JFileChooser is opened from a browse button on the initial window. I currently have it set up so that the browse button disposes of that first window and opens the JFileChooser window simultaneously. I would rather have the window be disposed *after* the user has selected their file in case they want to cancel and go back to the initial window - this is not currently possible.

Here's the relevant code:

```
class BrowseButton extends JButton {

    public BrowseButton(String name, final JPanel pane) {

        super(name);
        addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                JFileChooser fileopen = new JFileChooser();             
                FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("dwg files", "dwg");
                fileopen.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);

                int ret = fileopen.showDialog(pane, "Open");

                if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    File file = fileopen.getSelectedFile();
                    String[] layers = getFileLayers(file.getPath());
                    openLayerWindow(layers);
                }

            }
        });
        addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                dispose();
            }
        });
    }
```

and when the button is instantiated...

```
//Bottom Panel
    final JPanel bottom = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));

    BrowseButton browse = new BrowseButton("Browse...", bottom);
    browse.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_B);
    CloseButton close = new CloseButton("Close");
    close.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_C);

    bottom.add(close);
    bottom.add(browse);
    basic.add(bottom);
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Could you drop the `dispose`, and just `setVisible(false)` instead? Then check to see if a file was chosen or not.

Comment: JFileChooser can be put in a dialog.  That way, the user controls when to close the window by clicking on the OK or Cancel buttons.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of `SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor` to retrieve the containing window of your `BrowseButton` and dispose it only if the user choose the `APPROVE_OPTION`.

```
class BrowseButton extends JButton {

    public BrowseButton(String name, final JPanel pane) {

        super(name);
        addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                JFileChooser fileopen = new JFileChooser();             
                FileFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("dwg files", "dwg");
                fileopen.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);

                int ret = fileopen.showDialog(pane, "Open");

                if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                    SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(BrowsButton.this).dispose();
                    File file = fileopen.getSelectedFile();
                    String[] layers = getFileLayers(file.getPath());
                    openLayerWindow(layers);
                }

            }
        });
    }
```